# Ways to throttle ajax requests

Tags: jquery, delay, throttling

I'm using the following code [(written by another user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964501/throttling-an-ajax-livesearch-function) to throttle ajax requests in a livesearch function:

JSFiddle if you prefer a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4xLVp/

It seems buggy, though. Clearing values with `Ctrl+shift+back-arrow`, and typing again causes a flurry of requests. Blank values also cause a request. It dones't seem right, especially compared to [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), where request delays seem more measured.

```
    $('##tag-search').keyup(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        if (elem.val().length >= 2) {
            elem.data('search',search).clearQueue().stop().delay(1000).queue(function() {
                $.ajax({ // ajax stuff
                    'success': function(data){ /*show result*/ }
                });
                if (elem.data('search') !=  string) return;
            });                                             
        } else if (string.length <= 1) { /*show original content*/ }
    });
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just use `setTimeout`:

```
(function() {
    var timeout;
    $('#tag-search').keyup( function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        if (elem.val().length >= 2) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
               $.ajax({ // ajax stuff
                    'success': function(data){ /*show result*/ }
                });     
            }, 80); // <-- choose some sensible value here                                      
        } else if (string.length <= 1) { /*show original content*/ }
    });
}());
```

There is also a [debounce/throttle](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks. That's done the trick, I'm surprised it's that simple. Can you please explain what the clearTimeout() does and why it's needed?

Comment: setTimeout - sets a code which would be executed after some time, clearTimeout - removes that pending execution, it's needed to clear earlier peding ajax request before starting new one

Comment: BTW - I do not recommend removal of `if (elem.data('search') !=  string) return;` part, it prevents earlier ajax calls (lasting longer) from updating already changed results

Comment: @Jacek_FH: How? As far as I can see, this statement is doing nothing. It is not inside the Ajax call. The function will return after that statement anyway. *Edit:* Ah, in the original code (the one that the OP links to) this statement is inside the Ajax callback.