# Jquery event or function calls automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

is there any function which can be called after 5 seconds when user stops typing in Jquery?

Thanks

Comment: no. and then a couple more no's to put enough here. no no no

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967785/ways-to-throttle-ajax-requests

Comment: can you be more specific?  Do you have some example code?

Comment: @Jamiec why "no"? Simple setTimeout/clearTimeout will do the trick

Comment: What is the meaning of 'when user stops typing in Jquery'?

Comment: @WTK - totally, but there is nothing built-in to jQuery to do this "When the user stops typing"

Comment: @Jamiec You're right, I skipped the part about jQuery when reading question ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
function afterTypeProcess(){
   //Dosomething
}

var timeid;

$("input").keyup(function(){
   clearTimeout(timeid);
   timeid = setTimeout(afterTypeProcess, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just clear, and reset, your timeout on each `keyup` event:

```
​var countdown;
$("textarea:first").on("keyup", function(){
    clearTimeout(countdown);
    countdown = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Fired");
    }, 5000);
});​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FQtDn/

Comment: @2astalavista The reference to the timeout gets overwritten, but the queue isn't changed. Try removing the `clearTimeout` portion in the fiddle and watch your console as you type - it will be called five seconds after each keyup event.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: Ok, changed to Mozilla Developer link. Thanks for the info. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) plus [setTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do the trick. You can check the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6QCtj/2/)
For a text input

you can check for keyup using the following code

```
$("#entersomething").keyup(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("up"); }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RrbMT/)

```
$(document).on("change", ".test", function(){
    window.setTimeout(dothis, 5000);

});

function dothis(){
    alert('test');
}
```