# Stop Ajax if ? (Autcomplete with multiple values)

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

So, I'm working on a very simple autocomplete script with multiple values (seperated with a coma) using jQuery.
Suggestions start if the last tag length > 1, else it should not trigger and remove any suggestion.

Here is the code:

```
function show_tags () {
            var tags = jQuery( this ).val();
            var last_tag= getLast(tags);

            if (last_tag.length>1) {

                jQuery.ajax({
                  url: ajaxurl,
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {
                    'action': 'suggest_tags',
                    't': tags
                  }
                }).done(function(response) {
                    jQuery('.suggestions').html(response);
                });
            }
            else {
                jQuery('.suggestions').html('');
            }
        }

jQuery( ".search-field" ).on( "keyup", show_tags);
```

But...

I figured out that it might not be the best way to do this, since if someone type too quickly, the else part will trigger before the previous ajax requests are done.

How could I abort the previous requests if the user type a coma quickly after, and so, if last_tag length <=1 ?

I feel like I will have to rethink the whole thing just for that. Is there not a quick fix?
I'm kind of lost and tired.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you `disable` the element one the Ajax start, and `enable` it once finished, using [`.prop()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/), another way is for sure to [throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) Ajax calls (not sure if that plugin works for jQuery 3 though) :

```
function show_tags () {
    var textInput = jQuery( this );
    var tags = jQuery( this ).val();

    var last_tag= getLast(tags);

    if (last_tag.length>1) {
        textInput.prop( "disabled", true );
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: ajaxurl,
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            'action': 'suggest_tags',
            't': tags
          }
        }).done(function(response) {
            jQuery('.suggestions').html(response);
            textInput.prop( "disabled", false );
        });
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.suggestions').html('');
    }
}

jQuery( ".search-field" ).on( "keyup", show_tags);
```

Comment: Mmmhh, I thought about that, but I'm not sure this kind of solution is worth solving that kind of problem. As it would break (to me) the user experience, when here it just shows tags suggestions for a little too long, before another character input. If you understand what I mean.

Comment: @bobbrown, thats why I suggested throttle/debounce, which in my opinion is the best way to go for this, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967785/ways-to-throttle-ajax-requests

Comment: Yes sorry I was testing with your first solution and didn't see the editing, before answering (Also in that first solution, you might want to disable the input only if (last_tag.length>1), just in case someone find this). I'm not familiar with throttle/debounce, I'm going to give it a look. Thanks

Comment: done with editing, I really suggest that you check throttle/debounce, it enhance the user experience a lot, disabling element is good but for something like a button click ajax call but in your case debounce is better, since its a text input.

Comment: I read about it, but I'm not sure it would solve the problem? Maybe I am wrong, but, it just limits the number of ajax request, right? What if a coma is entered (and remove suggestions), but a previous request is still happening (lagging in the background), it would still show suggestions, i guess?

Comment: It should work for you, yes it limits the Ajax call this will prevent too many Ajax calls from happening that the user don't want a result for also this is good to reduce server load, and regarding the comma I think this is something that you have take into account, by make sure that your input is split properly before Ajax call happen.

Comment: I did try it, and it works well, I have to say... The only drawback is that it adds yet another dependency, which I'm always trying to avoid (that's why I didn't try jqueryui autocomplete). But yeah, it's a very light one... and it also helps with server loads... So... FINE! You're right! ;). I'll still wait to see if someone else have another suggestion, but I'll keep this for now, even though I think there might not be a better solution. Thanks a lot anyway! ** I'll give a day or two before accepting the answer.

Comment: No problem, take your time and its always better to see if there are better opinions and solutions.