# wait for jQuery getJSON to be complete to continue for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following 2 functions:

```js
function setPanelTo(panel,id){
  $.getJSON("https://e926.net/posts/"+id+".json?_client="+clientname, function( data ) {
    var img = document.createElement("img")
    img.classList.add("panel")
    img.src = data.post.file.url;
    comic.append(img)
  });
}

function getPoolByID(id){
  comic.innerHTML = "";
  $.getJSON("https://e926.net/pools/"+id+".json?_client="+clientname, function( data ) {
    for (var x = 0; x < data.post_ids.length; x++){
      setPanelTo(x,data.post_ids[x]);
    }
  });
}
```

and when I call the `getPoolByID();` function, it populates the 'comic' `<div>` element with images. However, the images do not appear in the correct order, which slightly undermines the point of a comic.
How do I make it so that the images don't load until the previous image has loaded?

Note: I've tried using a table, and while it worked, the images did not wrap when they reached the edge of the page, which is a must have for this.

Comment: Thanks.  Also see this related question [Ways to throttle ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967785/ways-to-throttle-ajax-requests?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use Image Placeholders**

There are a few ways to solve the problem. The simplest solution is to modify the code to generate placeholder images and assign each a sequence ID.  This ensures that the comic panels are in the correct order.  And as the getJSON() for each image completes it updates the image src with the actual url.

**Request Throttling**

The API [documentation](https://e926.net/help/api) says:

> E621/E926 have a hard rate limit of two requests per second. This is a
> hard upper limit and if you are hitting it, you are already going way
> too fast. Hitting the rate limit will result in a 503 HTTP response
> code. You should make a best effort not to make more than one request
> per second over a sustained period.

And your loop to pull images hits this limit, which is why not all of the images are returned.  So you may also need to add a timer to the loop to slow down the request rate, but this is outside the scope of the original question.

See related question for ideas: [Ways to throttle ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967785/ways-to-throttle-ajax-requests?rq=1)

**Run the code snippet to understand how it works:**

```js
function setPanelTo(panel,id){

  // Here we create an image placeholder BEFORE calling getJSON().

  comic.innerHTML += 
  '<img id="id' + id + '" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />';

  $.getJSON("https://e926.net/posts/"+id+".json?_client="+clientname, function( data ) {
  
    // And then we update each image once we have the actual url
  
    document.querySelector("#id" + id).src = data.post.file.url;
    
  });
}

function getPoolByID(id){
  
  comic.innerHTML = "";  
  
  $.getJSON("https://e926.net/pools/"+id+".json?_client="+clientname, function( data ) {
  
    for (var x = 0; x < data.post_ids.length; x++){
      setPanelTo(x,data.post_ids[x]);
    }

  });
}

// Test
let clientname = "noname";
getPoolByID("30251", "");
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
Image source: <a href="https://e926.net/pools/30251" target="_blank">https://e926.net/pools/30251</a>

<div id="comic"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```